# How to add data to a listView from XAML with databinding to my ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, microsoft-metro

I´m fairly new to XAML and Windows 8 app programming and programming overall. I´ve been trying this for days.
I have a ViewModel called PeopleConnector which contains an Observable Collection of People
I´ve set the DataContext of my XAML page to my ViewModel.
Now I want to be able to create a new Person in my View, with input from a textbox, and show it in my list with two way databinding.
What is the correct way to do this. I can make this work in the code behind of my XAML page but then I´m skipping my viewModel.
Is this possible through my ViewModel?

CODE

Person class is a simple Poco class and inherits BindableBase

My ViewModel (People Connector)

```
class PeopleConnector : BindableBase
{

    private ObservableCollection<Person> _people;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get { return _people; }
        set { _people = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public PeopleConnector()
    {
        People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        People.Add(new Person { Name = "Iris", About = "Developer that loves Metro style" });
        People.Add(new Person { Name = "Paul", About = "DBA with a thing for SQL Server 2012" });

    }

    public Person NewPerson { get; set; }

    public void AddNewPerson()
    {
        People.Add(new Person { Name = NewPerson.Name, About = NewPerson.About });
    }

}
```

My View (XAML page)

```
    <Page.DataContext>
    <local:PeopleConnector/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <ListView x:Name="AllItemsView" 
                  Width="200" 
                  Margin="40,20,0,0" 
                  Height="400" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  Background="DarkGray"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding People}">             
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"  Text="{Binding Path=About}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <StackPanel Width="200" Margin="20,50,0,0" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBlock>Name</TextBlock>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding NewPerson.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock>About</TextBlock>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding NewPerson.About, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
            <Button VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="30" Width="130" Click="Button_Click_1">Add</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few things wrong here:

First, you aren't initializing `NewPerson`. In your `PeopleConnector` constructor you'll need to initialize `NewPerson`.

Next, you have no way of telling your ViewModel that you clicked a button. Normally, you'd do this by binding an instance of ICommand on your ViewModel to your View (refer to DelegateCommand for a possible implementation). So your button would change to this:

```
<Button VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="30" Width="130" Command={Binding Path=AddPersonCommand}>Add</Button>
```

And your ViewModel constructor would look something like this:

```
public PeopleConnector()
{
    People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    People.Add(new Person { Name = "Iris", About = "Developer that loves Metro style" });
    People.Add(new Person { Name = "Paul", About = "DBA with a thing for SQL Server 2012" });
    NewPerson = new Person();
    _addPersonCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddNewPerson);
}

private readonly DelegateCommand _addPersonCommand;
public ICommand AddPersonCommand
{
    get { return _addPersonCommand; }
}
```